# Does my unit test care about too much

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have 2 concerns about my unit test method:

1. Do I test too much in one test method?
2. How can my test method name reflect all test expectations?

I asked myself when my method name says: `ReturnInvalidModelState`, then my 2 other `Asserts` are not correct. At least concerning the method name...

```
[Test]
public void Create_TemplateAlreadyExists_ReturnInvalidModelState()
{
    // ARRANGE
    TemplateViewModel templateViewModel = new TemplateViewModel { 
        Name = "MyTest" 
    };

    Mock<ITemplateDataProvider> mock1 = new Mock<ITemplateDataProvider>();
    Mock<IMappingEngine> mock2 = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();

    TemplateController controller = 
        new TemplateController(mock1.Object, mock2.Object);
    mock1.Setup(m => m.TemplateExists("MyTest")).Returns(true);
    // Set ModelState.IsValid to false
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name", 
                                        "This name already exists.");

    // ACT
    ActionResult result = controller.Create(templateViewModel);

    // ASSERT
    Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(PartialViewResult), result);
    Assert.AreEqual(templateViewModel, ((PartialViewResult)result).Model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TemplateViewModel templateViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid
        && !_templateDataProvider.TemplateExists(templateViewModel.Name))
    {

        Template template = 
            Mapper.Map<TemplateViewModel, Template>(templateViewModel);

        _templateDataProvider.AddTemplate(template);
        return new JsonNetResult(new { success = true });
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "This name already exists.");
    return PartialView(templateViewModel);
}
```

Comment: close? coward...who does not write his comment here.

Comment: I would suggest to keep one assert in each test method, that helps to avoid too much tests in one test method. Too much tests or assert in one method is not recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think that you are testing for too many things.

Start with renaming your test method. Your method signature should describe action, scenario and expected outcome.

If I were to rename your method, than I would end up with the following:

```
public void Create_DuplicateTemplate_ModelStateIsInvalidAndReturnsPartialViewResultAndPartialViewResultOfTypeTemplateViewModel() 
{ 
}
```

Your test is concerned with three things, rather than one. When it fails, you won't know straight away why it has failed.

Consider re-factoring this into smaller tests and encapsulating some of the arrangement logic so that it can be re-used.

**Edit:**

You made a good point in your comment regarding single test method having a single assertion. I agree with you on that one, as good as it sounds, often it's not sufficient.

Say I have the following action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(NewUserViewModel newUser)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(newUser);

    var newUserDTO = Mapper.Map<NewUserViewModel, NewUserDTO>(newUser);
    var userDTO = UserManagementService.RegisterUser(newUserDTO);

    var result = Mapper.Map<UserDTO, UserViewModel>(userDTO);

    TempData.Add("RegisteredUser", result);
    return RedirectToAction("RegisterSuccess");
}
```

I have the following unit test for this method:

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void Register_HttpPost_ValidViewModel_ReturnsRegisterSuccess()
        {
            // Arrange
            var autoMapperMock = this.mockRepository.DynamicMock<IMapper>();
            var userManagementServiceMock = this.mockRepository.DynamicMock<IUserManagementService>();

            var invalidRegistrationViewModel = new NewUserViewModel
            {
                LastName = "Lastname",
                FirstName = "Firstname",
                Username = null
            };

            autoMapperMock.Expect(a => a.Map<UserDTO, UserViewModel>(Arg<UserDTO>.Is.Anything)).Repeat.Once().Return(null);
            autoMapperMock.Expect(a => a.Map<NewUserViewModel, NewUserDTO>(Arg<NewUserViewModel>.Is.Anything)).Repeat.Once().Return(null);
            userManagementServiceMock.Expect(s => s.RegisterUser(Arg<NewUserDTO>.Is.Anything)).Repeat.Once();

            autoMapperMock.Replay();

            var controller = new AccountController
            {
                Mapper = autoMapperMock,
                UserManagementService = userManagementServiceMock
            };

            this.mockRepository.ReplayAll();

            // Act
            var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Register(invalidRegistrationViewModel);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue((string)result.RouteValues["Action"] == "RegisterSuccess");
        }
```

As you can see, I set up multiple expectations on my mock:

- I expect AutoMapper to be called twice
- I expect UserManagementService to be called once

At the end of the test I have a single assertion that checks whether user was re-directed to the correct route.

So where do I check my assertions? I create another method that makes sure that my expectations have been met:

```
    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        try
        {
            this.mockRepository.VerifyAll();
        }
        finally
        {                
        }
}
```

So you are right, I have three assertions instead of one, but I structure my code in such a way so it appears that I have only one assertion.

Comment: ok then I would remove the assert about the modelstate because if the modelstate.IsValid = true then there must be a PartialViewResult.You Agree? Then I have still left 2 asserts = 2 tests.

Comment: Very often a unit test also involves mocking where I have to verify a method call this is also an assertion. I think 1 test == 1 assert is religious thinking far away from reality. What do you think?

Comment: @Elisa I disagree. Sure, there will be exceptions, but in most cases, 1 assertion per test is nice and practical. It simply gives you more clean and easy-to-read code. The way to achieve this though, is to move as much code as possible *out* of the test itself (see my answer, for instance). Working this way will help you avoid putting several assertions in the same test simply to avoid repeating the same code too many times.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend moving all of the "Arrange" and "Act" code into a `Setup()` method, and split the rest into three tests. This will make each individual test much easier to read, and let you give each test a name that corresponds better to the actual assert it contains.

```
private TemplateViewModel _templateViewModel;
private ITemplateDataProvider _mock2;
private IMappingEngine _mock2;
private TemplateController _controller;
private ActionResult _result;

[Setup]
public void Setup(){
    // ARRANGE
    _templateViewModel = new TemplateViewModel { Name = "MyTest" };

    _mock1 = new Mock<ITemplateDataProvider>();
    _mock2 = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();

    _controller = new TemplateController(_mock1.Object, _mock2.Object);
    _mock1.Setup(m => m.TemplateExists("MyTest")).Returns(true);

    // Set ModelState.IsValid to false
    _controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Name", 
                                        "This name already exists.");

    _result = controller.Create(_templateViewModel);
}


[Test]
public void Create_TemplateAlreadyExists_ModelStateIsInvalid()
{
    Assert.IsFalse(_controller.ModelState.IsValid);
}


[Test]
public void Create_TemplateAlreadyExists_ResultIsPartialViewResult()
{
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(PartialViewResult), _result);
}


[Test]
public void Create_TemplateAlreadyExists_ResultModelMatchesTemplateModel()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(_templateViewModel, ((PartialViewResult)_result).Model);
}
```

Comment: I see there a problem: I can not run this setup for a Update_Template_xxx,Delete_Template_xxx and Get_Template_xxx test. And when you want to make a Create_Template_ModelStateIsValid test you can not run this setup because of AddModelError... Your suggestion seems not practical to me.

Comment: Well there are several solutions to those problems. One could be to create these tests in different files, for instance one called `When_creating_templates.cs`, one called `when_getting_templates.cs`, and one called `when_deleting_templates.cs`. That way, you could use different setups for each situation, and create several tests in each. Another alternative is to keep most of the setup method here, but move the last (or last two) line into each test, as needed in the differing situations. You still end up with less repetition, and improved readability.

Comment: PS: Remember that even if you do set some value or property in the `SetUp()` method, you can still override that setting in a specific `Test()` method if you need something to be different in just that test. This will allow the rest of the tests to make use of the "shared" code in the SetUp.